# MySQL - find N prev and next entries given an ID and order clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this structure

```
ID  Value  Price
1     a      10
2     b      30
3     c      30
4     d      20
5     e      5
6     f      40
```

I have a select to get list ordered by price

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY Price ASC
```

which gives me

```
ID  Value  Price
5     e      5
1     a      10
4     d      20
2     b      30
3     c      30
6     f      40
```

Now on my web page, a user clicks on an item with `ID=2` and wants some details about it. However, on this detail page, I want to show N previous and next items in order. How can I obtain N previous and next items, given the `ID` and `ORDER BY` clause?

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() will give selected row number. Then +/-N in LIMIT.

Comment: what about ties?  for ties with your target row, do you want them *plus* N previous and N next, or do they count towards your N+1 total rows (and if so, how exactly?)  for ties in the previous/next rows, do you want N distinct values, N plus possibly more if the most distant price has ties, or just always N with arbitrary ties chosen to show?

Answer (score 1):

```
drop table if exists mytable;
create table mytable (ID serial primary key,  Value char(1),  Price int);
insert into mytable values
(1,'a',10),
(2,'b',30),
(3,'c',30),
(4,'d',20),
(5,'e',5),
(6,'f',40);

select t2.id, t2.value, t2.price
from (
  select id, row_number() over (order by price asc) as rownum
  from mytable
) as t1
join (
  select *, row_number() over (order by price asc) as rownum
  from mytable
) as t2
  on t2.rownum between t1.rownum-2 and t1.rownum+2
where t1.id = 2
order by price asc;
```

Output, tested on MySQL 8.0.29:

```
+----+-------+-------+
| id | value | price |
+----+-------+-------+
|  1 | a     |    10 |
|  4 | d     |    20 |
|  2 | b     |    30 |
|  3 | c     |    30 |
|  6 | f     |    40 |
+----+-------+-------+
```

Comment: does this actually perform well with a large table (with an index on price)?  I'd be more inclined to union two limit queries, if this is how ties should be resolved.  even with this approach, I'd add id to the order bys just so consistent order between the queries is guaranteed.

Comment: The OP wanted a solution that didn't use UNION (a sentence that has since been edited out), and this is what I came up with. Probably the performance is not good, since it does two table-scans to get the numbered rows, but performance was not mentioned in the criteria.